# All columns show #Deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, odbc

I read this article and tried everything in it and the problem still exists. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/128809

The data is in SQL Server 2008 R2. I have two tables with 81 rows each. One has 2 columns and the other 5. Both tables have primary keys and unique indexes. The table with 5 columns links to Access 2010 fine. The table with 2 columns shows 81 rows and both columns filled with #Deleted.

The two tables need a single join so I tried creating a view and linking to that. The three columns in the view all show #Deleted. Only one of the columns in the view is from the table that has the problem.

I tried doing INSERT INTO query in SQL Server to create a table with the three columns. I then added a primary key and unique index. Still, I get three columns of #Deleted when I link to the resulting table.

The data types in both tables are all nvarchar, int and there is a bigint in the problem table.

Out of curiosity I added a new column of type int and moved all of the bigint values to the new int column of the table I created. I then dropped the bigint column and it worked! I could link to it. So my option now is to create a stored procedure that creates the table periodically and changes the data type in the one column from bigint to int.

I would rather not. Does anyone know why Access 2010 doesn't seem to like bigint?

Greg

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I posted I thought of a solution - I created a view and cast the bigint as an int. Access likes it.

Comment: That makes sense. There is not Access equivalent for bigint. When linking Access to SQL Server it is important to only use data types that Access Supports. The newer versions of SQL Server have some new data types like Date, Datetime2, etc. These are some that Access will not recognize.

Comment: Odd that this never came up before for us. We have three instances of SQL Server with dozens of databases and link tables to dozens of Access databases.